# Custom customer attribute not saving

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.2.3, eav-attributes

I have created a custom customer attribute using the following code:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\AccountActivated\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'account_activated',
            [
            'type'         => 'int',
            'label'        => 'Account Activated',
            'input'        => 'boolean',
            'required'     => false,
            'visible'      => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position'     => 999,
            'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $accountActivated = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'account_activated');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $accountActivated->setData(
        'used_in_forms',
        ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_register_address']

    );
        $accountActivated->save();
    }
}
```

The attribute appears in the database, and in the appropriate forms on the frontend. However, no values are saved in the backend. From watching one of Max Pronko's videos I added the following in etc/extension_attributes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerExtensionInterface">
    <attribute code="account_activated" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think,
You have to assign that attribute to default attribute set.as given below

Refer $this->customerSetupFactory to      Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

```
     $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'account_activated')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);
```